# SOQL join in salesforce

Tags: soql

How i can access attachment id from this query..

```
List<Email__c> e=[SELECT email_body__c,(SELECT Id,Name FROM Attachments) FROM Email__C where id='emailobjectid'];

for(email__c e1:e)
 {
                        System.debug(e1.Attachments.id);
 }

Getting error.. Invalid foreign key relationship Email__c.Attachments
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the query.

```
List<Email__c> e=[SELECT id, email_body__c FROM Email__C where id='emailobjectid'];

for(email__c e1:e){
     List<Attachments> attList = [SELECT Id,Name FROM Attachments where parentId=:e1.id];
     for(Attachment att:attList)
          System.debug(att.id+'   '+att.name);
 }
```